# How can i create only one time use splash screen for my android app

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

I want to create app in which splash screen came only one time.
like i just downloaded the application from playstore and when i pressed on application icon. only very first time splash screen showed. for rest of the time. it don't open like go straight way on second activity. How can i do this. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a launcher activity without an UI and SharedPreferences:

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("App", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Get value from shared preferences, 
    // if null (app is run first time) the default value (second argument) is returned
    boolean isFIrstRun = preferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    if (isFIrstRun) {
        // set isFirstRun to false
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

        // launch splash screen activity
    } else {
        // Launch other activity
    }
}
```

}

And make sure LauncherActivity is set as the launcher activity in the app manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```